# How Does Babel Know To Treat A Module As A Module

Tags: javascript, import, module, export, ecmascript-6

I have gone through [2ality article](http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html) on Modules, however, I am confused, how does the system know to treat a module as a module?

```
import React from "react";
import { hello } from "./hello.js";

var Ctrl = React.createClass ({
    render : function () {
        return (
            <div .... random data
            ></div>
        );
    }
});
export default Ctrl;
```

To me, a module is just a file with global code written in it. We reference the module via its filename.

However, I wonder how does this all gel together when we build the production build.

How does the system know that this is a module & not just global varaibles being declared?

Is it the `import / export` commands that actually make it say: 'aha, this is a module!'

Excuse the newbie question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it the `import` / `export` commands that actually make it say: 'aha, this is a module!'

Yes!

More precisely, the `import` keyword instructs the JavaScript engine (or transpiler) to load an external file as a module.

Comment: no the import keyword does not instruct a javascript engine or transpiler
**technically it will one day, but not today, as modules are coming officially to javascript

Answer (score 0):

if by system you mean the browser, it doesn't know, you normally use another tool that implements the idea of modules for you, and it transforms (puts in code) that act as a module system for you that the browser understands.

some tools like do this is require in node, browserify, webpack
that*, not like